# How can I programmatically detect if some text is visible or has overflowed in an InDesign document using ExtendScript?

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

I am building an InDesign panel with ExtendScript which finds text and shows it to the user. To do this, I use the `showText()` method of [the Character object](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Character.html#showText). The problem is that sometimes the text I'm looking for doesn't appear because, even though the method does show the right page at the right place, the text has overflown and is not visible.

Is there a way to check if the text is visible or not? Ideally, I would like to be able to fall back on the story editor if the text cannot be seen as-is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may call the baseline property for the text in a try/catch statement. If text is visible, baseline will return a value, otherwise it will raise an error.

Loic

Comment: Thanks. Kinda looks like a hack though, so I'll wait this out a bit to see if there is a non-error-throwing solution to this.

Answer (score 4):

To check the situation for an individual character, see the parentTextFrames property, it returns an array with 0 or 1 frames. In rare cases of insertion points whose left side is in one frame while the right side is in the following, you get two frames.

```
app.selection[0].characters.item(0).parentTextFrames.length
```

You can also compare the index of your character against the last index in the last text container of the story, e.g.

```
app.selection[0].parentStory.textContainers.pop().characters.lastItem().index
```

Of course you should first see whether there is overflow at all ...

```
app.selection[0].parentStory.overflows
```

Comment: I just made a function based on your solution and it worked for me, thanks!  
function checkNodeInOverflow(node){
    var insp = node.insertionPoints[0];
    return (insp.parentStory.overflows && insp.parentTextFrames.length == 0) ? true : false;
}
BTW, this is only to see if an XML node is in the overset.